# How many concurrent connections does ADAM allow?

Tags: adam

Is there a limit on number of concurrent connections to ADAM. Is is configurable?

-- How many concurrent connections from a same user could be established?
-- How many concurrent connections from different users could be established?

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theoretical limit is 65534. In practice I have seen 25,000 or so concurrently for a single server. If this doesn't meet your needs, replicating and load balancing ADAM is quite easy.

Each connection to ADAM uses up an ephemeral port and Windows by default limits them to 5,000. You can [change](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q196271/) that in the registry as high as 65534. This pool is shared by any application using TCP/IP on the server.

Also, each connection doesn't go away right after the user is done with it. It goes into a TIME_WAIT state and still uses one of your ports. See this article for [details](http://blog.port80software.com/2004/12/07/hurry-up-and-time_wait/).